# Why mysql unique let duplicate values to insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database, duplicates, unique

I have a problem with mysql.
I configured my columns and sat **unique** for some column, but when I execute an update with a **duplicated data** on a **unique column** it completes it, so now I can **set duplicate values for unique**.

Could somebody tell me why it happens and how can I correct it?

*Thanks in advance for your answer and your time.*

This is the structure

[image]

These are the records

[image]

I'm using usbWebserver v8.6

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: No it doesn't.  Unique columns are enforced, so you are missing something.  Your question needs to provide more details.

Comment: Show before and after data to support your question.

Comment: Linked images about the structure and the records

Comment: It's not wise to pick your username column as PK. Now, did you made the "unique" changes (through that UI) after having these data in the table? It's less likely that you can insert a duplicate id if a column has an `UNIQUE` constraint. Please provide an example of new insert query WITH response on display name `u1`.

Answer (score 0):

Added a new record to it where display name is "u1":

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEMiT.png)

Answer (score -1):

i believe you have set the ENTIRE ROW to be unique.

so you can duplicate some columns as long as the whole record has one small difference somewhere..

Comment: That's wrong: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique-constraint/